# Google Sheet App Script - Spreading values into separate tabs by a dimension

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a question regarding Google App Script

Below is the code I tried...

@Tanaike has helped me with the below code, but now the issue is to put 3 dimensions

```
function SpreadbyStoreName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // remove header row values from array
  values.shift();

  // data structure
  var ds = {};
  values.forEach(function(row) {
    var storename= row[0]; // 1st col
    var fruits = row[1]; // 2nd col
    var notformatteddate = row[2]; // 3rd col
    var startdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(notformatteddate), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")

    ds[storename] = ds[storename] || {}; // vendor
    ds[storename][fruits] = ds[storename][fruits] || {};
    ds[storename][fruits][startdate] = ds[storename][fruits][startdate] || [];
    ds[storename][fruits][startdate] = [parseInt(row[3]), parseInt(row[4])];
  });

  var rs = {};
  Object.keys(ds).forEach(function(s) {
    rs[s] = rs[s] || [];
    Object.keys(ds[s]).forEach(function(f) {
      rs[s][f] = rs[s][f] || [];
      Object.keys(ds[s]).forEach(function(sd) {
        if(ds[s][f][sd]) {
          rs[s][f].push([sd, ds[s][f][sd][0], ds[s][f][sd][1]]);
        }else{
          rs[s][f].push([s, 0, 0]);
        }
      })
    })
  })

  Logger.log(rs)

  Object.keys(ds).forEach(function(v) {
    var headers = [[s, 'Fruits'].join(' '), 'NumberSold', 'UniqueSold'];
    ds[s].unshift(headers);
    try {
      ss.insertSheet(headers[0]);
    } catch (e) {}
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(headers[0]);
    sh.clear();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, ds[s].length, 3).setValues(ds[s]);
  })
}
```

Basically, the purpose of the above code is to take [store name, fruits, date created, number sold, unique sold] and split the data by "Store name" column into separate tab in Google Sheet.

Using the above code, I cannot get the proper object format that can be used

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/171S9c079hHBgqgsouZPb09k220HEFTF13y2bB187-N8/edit?usp=sharing

Above is the link to the sample data

Answer (score 0):

**Creating and Loading Sheets by Store Name**

```
function sheetByStoreName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet148');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header=values[0];
  values.splice(0,1);
  //Loading the object
  var ds = {eA:[]};//for store names and object names
  values.forEach(function(row) {
    if(!ds.hasOwnProperty(row[0])) {
      ds[row[0]]=[]; //new store
      ds[row[0]].push({fruit:row[1],datecreated:Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[2]), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy"),numbersold:row[3],uniquesold:row[4]});
      ds.eA.push(row[0]);
    }else{
      ds[row[0]].push({fruit:row[1],datecreated:Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[2]), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy"),numbersold:row[3],uniquesold:row[4]});
    }

  });  
  //Looking at the output 
  var html="<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>";
  for(var i=0;i<ds.eA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<ds[ds.eA[i]].length;j++)  {
      Logger.log('--%s,%s,%s,%s,%s',ds.eA[i],ds[ds.eA[i]][j].fruit,ds[ds.eA[i]][j].datecreated,ds[ds.eA[i]][j].numbersold,ds[ds.eA[i]][j].uniquesold);
        html+=Utilities.formatString("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>",ds.eA[i],ds[ds.eA[i]][j].fruit,ds[ds.eA[i]][j].datecreated,ds[ds.eA[i]][j].numbersold,ds[ds.eA[i]][j].uniquesold);
    }
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Example');
  //Loading the sheets
  for(var i=0;i<ds.eA.length;i++) {
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName(ds.eA[i]);
    if(!sh) {
      var sh=ss.insertSheet(ds.eA[i]);
    }
    sh.clearContents();//clear each stores sheet
    sh.appendRow(header);//put the header on first
    for(var j=0;j<ds[ds.eA[i]].length;j++)  {
      sh.appendRow([ds.eA[i],ds[ds.eA[i]][j].fruit,ds[ds.eA[i]][j].datecreated,ds[ds.eA[i]][j].numbersold,ds[ds.eA[i]][j].uniquesold]);
    }
  }  
}
```